# 'ESRCH', errno: 'ESRCH', syscall: 'kill' running node.js application on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, puppeteer

I am getting the below error when trying to install a node application. I have followed the steps in both documents in the links below on Ubuntu. Just cannot find out what else to do

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch

The exact steps for installation are as follows

```
$ npm i -g npm
```

> /home/gbaz/.npm-global/bin/npm ->
>   /home/gbaz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
>   /home/gbaz/.npm-global/bin/npx ->
>   /home/gbaz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
>
> npm@5.5.1 added 460 packages in 88.918s

```
$ npm install -g aws-azure-login
```

> /home/gbaz/.npm-global/bin/aws-azure-login ->
>   /home/gbaz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/bin/index.js
>
> puppeteer@0.13.0 install
>   /home/gbaz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer
>   node install.js Downloading Chromium r515411 - 95.4 Mb
>   [====================] 100% 0.0s Chromium downloaded to
>   /home/gbaz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-515411
>
> aws-azure-login@1.0.1 added 106 packages in 93.44s

```
$ aws-azure-login
```

> Logging in with profile 'default'... Error: kill ESRCH at
>   Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11) at process.kill
>   (internal/process.js:183:18) at forceKillChrome
>   (/home/gbaz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:162:19)
>   at killChrome
>   (/home/gbaz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:147:9) at Function.launch
>   (/home/gbaz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:137:7) at at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7) code: 'ESRCH', errno: 'ESRCH',
>   syscall: 'kill'

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz 189222016 Dec  1 14:57 chrome

-rw------- 1 gbaz gbaz    803598 Dec  1 14:57 chrome_100_percent.pak

-rw------- 1 gbaz gbaz   1069093 Dec  1 14:57 chrome_200_percent.pak

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz     23328 Dec  1 14:57 chrome_sandbox

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz      5087 Dec  1 14:57 chrome-wrapper
-rw------- 1 gbaz gbaz  10170896 Dec  1 14:57 icudtl.dat

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz    764192 Dec  1 14:57 libclearkeycdmadapter.so

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz   2849360 Dec  1 14:57 libclearkeycdm.so

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz    539352 Dec  1 14:57 libEGL.so

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz   6372616 Dec  1 14:57 libGLESv2.so

drwxrwxrwx 0 gbaz gbaz       512 Dec  1 14:57 locales

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz   3480080 Dec  1 14:57 nacl_helper

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz      9736 Dec  1 14:57 nacl_helper_bootstrap

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz   3592012 Dec  1 14:57 nacl_helper_nonsfi

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz   3540528 Dec  1 14:57 nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe

-rw------- 1 gbaz gbaz    208801 Dec  1 14:57 natives_blob.bin

-rw------- 1 gbaz gbaz      2540 Dec  1 14:57 product_logo_48.png

drwxrwxrwx 0 gbaz gbaz       512 Dec  1 14:57 resources

-rw------- 1 gbaz gbaz  13583784 Dec  1 14:57 resources.pak

-rw------- 1 gbaz gbaz   1332440 Dec  1 14:57 snapshot_blob.bin

drwxrwxrwx 0 gbaz gbaz       512 Dec  1 14:57 swiftshader

-rw------- 1 gbaz gbaz   1738524 Dec  1 14:57 v8_context_snapshot.bin

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz     37394 Dec  1 14:57 xdg-mime

-rwx------ 1 gbaz gbaz     33273 Dec  1 14:57 xdg-settings

```
~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-515411/chrome-linux$ chrome
```

**chrome: command not found**

Comment: Aws-azure-login uses Puppeteer and headless Chrome under the hood, and it's possible Chrome is failing to start (one possible reason is missing shared libraries). What happens if you try starting the Puppeteer-bundled Chrome manually with `~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-*/chrome-linux/chrome`?

Comment: chrome: command not found

Comment: The binary seems to be there, but you probably don't have "." in your PATH,  so the command should be `./chrome` - does that work?

Comment: (origin-federated) gbaz@DESKTOP-EPRVA20:~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-515411/chrome-linux$ ./chrome
[93:93:1215/160524.724131:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(126)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.